# Classificar coluna de um data frame em R

Tags: r

Tenho um data frame com `89000` linhas e numa das coluna aparece o grau de parentesco com o funcionário. Preciso dividir em `4 classes`, a saber:

- Classe 1 - Conjugue/Filhos
- Classe 2 - Mãe/Pai
- Classe 3 - Irmãos
- OUTRAS - Outros Parentescos

Preciso criar uma coluna no data frame que insere a classe do parentesco do funcionário (preciso manter o parentesco original na base). Fiz com uma série de `ifelse` aninhados, mas gostaria de saber se há alguma solução mais "elegante".

```
ifelse(base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe1, base.dados$CLASSE <- "CLASSE 1",
                              ifelse(base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe2, base.dados$CLASSE <- "CLASSE 2",
                                     ifelse(base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe3, base.dados$CLASSE <- "CLASSE 3", "OUTRAS")))
```

Comment: Coloca as tags pra identificar a linguagem, e tenta ser mais claro, não consegui entender direito sua pergunta

Comment: Veja se ficou mais claro Samuel

Comment: Em vez de `base.dados$CLASSE <- "CLASSE 1"` faça só `"CLASSE 1"`. E o mesmo para os outros. Mais exatamente, `base.dados$CLASSE <- ifelse(...etc...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra mim, a forma mais elegante seria criar uma função que simplifique a cadeia de `ifelse`, e até generalize a transformação da função para outras situações. Exemplo:

```
classes_parentescos <- list("CLASSE 1"=c("conjuge", "filho"), 
                "CLASSE 2"=c("mae", "pai"), 
                "CLASSE 3"=c("outros")
                )

get_class_name <- function(x, classes=classes_parentescos){
        pos <- grep(x, classes)
        names(classes[pos])
}

base.dados$CLASSE <- sapply(base.dados$Parentesco, get_class_name)
```

Comment: Está a dar-me erro: `promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`. Será por ter `classes=classes`?

Comment: Estranho, na minha máquina o código é executado sem nenhum alerta, e normalmente esse tipo de abordagem nos argumentos também não me traz problema, . Você tentou tirar o argumento `classes` da função para ver se elimina o problema ?

Comment: Sim, quando tirei executou bem. Então mudei o nome do argumento, mantendo o valor por defeito, para `class = classes` e também não houve problema. (no `grep` passou a ser `class`, claro.)

Comment: O seguinte código, mais simples e que não tem nada a ver com a questão do OP, reproduz o problema: `f<-function(y,x=x)2*y+x;x<-1:5;sapply(6:10,f)`.

Comment: Realmente, agora me deu esse erro...  vendo essa resposta [aqui](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/180902.html), parece ser um conflito no  `environment`. Não ficou claro pra mim o que acontece, mas bom saber que o R não trata muito bem essas situações.

Comment: Editei a resposta para outras pessoas não passarem por essa problema.

Answer (score 3):

Como não temos um exemplo de `base.dados`, criei uma `data.frame`.
Se quiser evitar tantos `ifelse` pode fazer algo assim.

```
set.seed(6399)  # Torma o código reprodutível

classe1 <- c("Conjugue", "Filho", "Filha")
classe2 <- c("Mãe", "Pai")
classe3 <- c("Irmão", "Irmã")
classe4 <- c("Tio", "Tia", "Avô", "Avó")

base.dados <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:20,
    Parentesco = sample(c(classe1, classe2, classe3, classe4), 20, TRUE)
)
base.dados

base.dados$CLASSE <- "OUTRAS"
base.dados$CLASSE[base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe1] <- "CLASSE 1"
base.dados$CLASSE[base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe2] <- "CLASSE 2"
base.dados$CLASSE[base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe3] <- "CLASSE 3"
```

Se tiver valores `NA` na base, deve usar `which` no indíce lógico. A primeira linha mantém-se, só as outras é que mudam.

```
base.dados$CLASSE <- "OUTRAS"
base.dados$CLASSE[which(base.dados$Parentesco %in% classe1)] <- "CLASSE 1"
```

E o mesmo para as outras classes.